# Display linear layout over the CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I want to show  linearLayout(id=linear_img) over CollapsingToolbarLayout as shown in screeshot first.
    I set the minimum height of CollapsingToolbarLayout to 200 but when I scrollup the linearlayout hide behind the CollapsingToolbarLayout as shown in screenshot second.
    I have shared my code and here is the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/LTUwXhPv
    Please give me any idea to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

[image: I need this result]

[image: Getting this result]

Comment: Try adding this app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in your LinearLayout.

Comment: @ajantha: Thank you for quick reply. but it's not working...